# How to determine $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

i know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}) = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}] = \{a+b(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}) \space \text{with} \space a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. And i think the answer is 2 because we got a lineair combination of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $b\sqrt{-2}$ but i don't know how to prove this correctly.... can i get hints/tips/tricks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\alpha =\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}\Rightarrow \alpha -\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{-2}\Rightarrow (\alpha -\sqrt{2})^2=-2\Rightarrow (\alpha -\sqrt{2})^2+2=0$

$\alpha$ satisfies a second degree polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$

So.....

Comment: This is a good hint. To make sure the OP understands, there is still the issue of irreducibility of this polynomial to be considered.

Comment: hahahaha thanks this is very helpful! But our second degree polynomial is now in the form $X^{2}+2$ and this is irreducibel because 1,-1,2,-2(monic polynomial and zeros should divide 2) but $f(1,-1,2,-2)!= 0$. And because this is the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}$ over $\sqrt{2}$ we are finished!

Comment: @KeesTil : well done! you have shown there are no integer roots... but there is a problem of having rational roots... can you clear that ambiguity?

Comment: o yes you're right... Can i only use this theorem in $\mathbb{Z}$? I guess Eisenstein can do the trick as well with p=2.

Comment: apart from that you have another trouble... you can use rational root theorem (that is what you mean when you say $1,-1,2,-2$) only for polynomial with integer coefficients... you can say $X^2+2$ has no rational roots but then... does it say $(X\sqrt{2})^2+2$ has no rational roots??

Comment: o yes i finally get what you mean. I got a root with a factor $\sqrt{6}$ (using the abc-formula), but this element does not belong in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) so that's probably why its irreducible.

Comment: @KeesTil : You need to be more precise.. but this is enough for time being... well done :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$? In particular, think about the fact that $( \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-2})\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (Why?)(It might be nice to use the fact that you have a quadratic to prove irreducibility)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{-2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{-1})$, since $\sqrt{-1} = ((\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{-2}) - \sqrt{2})/\sqrt{2}$.  So, the degree is at most 2, and it is at least 2 because $\sqrt{-1} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2}}=\frac{\sqrt 2-\sqrt{-2}}{4} $$

Since $4\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2})$, $\frac{4}{\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2}}=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{-2}\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2})\Rightarrow \sqrt{2},\sqrt{-2}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2})$.

$ \frac{\sqrt{-2}}{\sqrt 2}=i\in\Bbb Q$.  It's plain to see that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2})\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$, so we have $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2})\cong\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, i)$.  $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i):\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)]=2.$

Comment: It's plain to see that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2})\subseteq\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$, i feel like an idiot, but i don't understand why this is true. Can you explain it for me?

Comment: $\sqrt 2+\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{2}(1+i)\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$ by closure, so all elements in the former field extension must be in the latter.